# if(:visible) slide up with a delay

Tags: jquery, if-statement, slidedown, slideup

I'm trying to have a page slide down and then another page slide up. But, for some reason, I can't figure it out.

http://maximsiebert.com/unamed/Untitled-1.html

If you look on here, you can see that if I click the `About` navigation link, the page slides up, if I click again it slides back down. Same for the `Contact page`.

The problem is, while, I have the `About page` up and I click on the contact link, I need the `About page` to slide down, while the `Contact page` slides up, vice versa. But I can't seem to get it to work.

Here's my code: 
ps: in "divPages" I have #aboutpage and #contactpage

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $('.about').click(function() {
    if (!$('#aboutpage').is(":visible")) {
    $('#portfolio').slideUp(1000);
        $('#aboutpage').slideDown(1000);
    }else{
        $('#portfolio').slideDown(1000);
        $('#aboutpage').slideUp(1000);
    }

});
```

});

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.contact').click(function() {
    if (!$('#contactpage').is(":visible")) {
        $('#portfolio').slideUp(1000);
        $('#contactpage').slideDown(1000);
    }else{
        $('#portfolio').slideDown(1000);
        $('#contactpage').slideUp(1000);
    }

});
```

});

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.welcome').click(function() {
    if ($(divPages).is(":visible")) {
        $('#portfolio').slideDown(1000);
        $(divPages).slideUp(1000);
        }else{
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
    }

});
```

});

Answer (score 1):

Your about page is still there but hidden somewhere behind. I son't think this is the full extnd of your problem but it can be a big part of it.

after any slideDown() add .css({'z-index':'-1'}); as in and after ans slideUp() add .css({'z-index':'100'});

```
$('#about').slideDown(1000).css({'z-index':'-1'});
$('#contact').slideDown(1000).css({'z-index':'100'});
```

i've exprienced the same problem with EI on a cross-fading slide show. The other pic was staying over the other one so you tough it didn'T work.

Hope this helps.

EDIT: affter taking another look, the about stayed hidden according to my firebug. You sould then also check if it's visible or not and change the display if needed.

This can be achieve with the .is(':visible') like so:

```
if($('#about').is(':visible') == false) $('#about').show();
```

reuse and change the html pointer for your other elements as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I would instead have a single class shared across all menu items that have your click event bound to.  Then, add a class to keep track of which item is currently shown.

**last edit** Add the class `.menu-item` and data attribute `data-content-div` equal to the content div's id to your menu li's.

`<li class="about menu-item" data-content-div="contactpage">about</li>`

And try this code in replace of what you have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.menu-item').click(function() {
        if ( $(this).hasClass('menu-active') )
        {
            var contentDiv = $(this).data('content-div');
            $('.menu-active').removeClass('menu-active');
            $('#' + contentDiv).slideDown(1000);
        }
        else if ( $('.menu-active').length )
        {      
            var menuItem = $(this);
            var hideDiv = $('.menu-active').data('content-div');
            $('.menu-active').removeClass('menu-active');
            $('#' + hideDiv).slideDown(500, function() { 
                menuItem.addClass('menu-active');
                $('#' + menuItem.data('content-div') ).slideUp(1000);
            });
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).addClass('menu-active');
            $('#' + $(this).data('content-div') ).slideUp(1000);
        }

    });
});
```

​

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vLtsC/2/) where it would work, if I had all your styles.
​

Comment: `hasClass`/`addClass` take class names without dots.

Comment: I do want it to slide down once they click the same menu item, for example if I click about, it slides up, if I click it again it goes down. The issue I'm having is that I want once the about slide is up, if they click on contact, the about slide slides down, and then the contact slide slides up.

Comment: @MaximSiebert - take a look at that last edit.  You can use the callback on the slide functions to get the effect you want.  The callback is fired once the `slideDown()` has finished.

Comment: @MaximSiebert - added an example of using the callback with your current code

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, it causes the contact slide to slide from top to bottom, then disappear, and then slide bottom to top and stay.

Comment: @kmfk what i'm trying to achieve is basically, on .contact click if #aboutpage is visible, #aboutpage slide down, #contact page slide up